# How can I add a new line to jquery flot ticks

Tags: jquery, flot, timeserieschart

I am using [JQuery Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) to create some graphs. So far I have managed to format my Ticks using tickformatter

The graph looks like this: http://i1358.photobucket.com/albums/q779/Angel_Ruiz_Morales/Capture.gif

The only problem I am having now is that I would like the Ticks to appear as follows:
Today\n{TIME}

I have tried adding \n character and see it appended but for some reason flot still displays Today {TIME} inline rather than on separate lines.

Does any one know a way to introduce a new line ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a `<br>` instead of `\n`.  The tick labels are HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
 timeformat: "%m/%d/%y <br> %H:%M:%S"
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/72u66r0m/